# A limit proof question?

Tags: calculus, limits

```
I think this is a limit proof question, but I wasn't sure. Any help?
```

Use a graph to find the largest number  $\delta > 0$ such that  if $|x-1|<\delta$,  then $|x^3-5x+6-2| < \varepsilon$ when $\varepsilon=0.2$

Comment: Yes, this is a limit proof question.

Comment: Did you plot $|x^3-5x+6-2| < \varepsilon $ yet?

Comment: The question is about limits, but there is no sign of a proof...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the graph of $y = x^3-5x+6$ as well as $y=2$ and $y=2\pm\varepsilon$. Can you read off the answer?

[image]

If you find the first graph difficult to read, here's $y = |x^3-5x+6-2|$ together with $y=\varepsilon$.

[image]

Comment: ooohh thank you! so the answer would be anything between .911<delta<1.124?

Comment: @user57172 No, $x$ can be between $0.911$ and $1.124$. What does that say about $\delta$?

Comment: would I have to subtract 1 from those?

Comment: @user57172 $-0.089 < x-1 < 0.124$, so how large can you choose $\delta$ to ensure that $-\delta < x-1 < \delta$?

Comment: you can choose up to .124?

Comment: @user57172 No, just $0.089$. (Otherwise it could happen that $x = 0.9$ for example, and this value of $x$ does *not* satisfy the required inequality.)

Comment: Oh, so then any delta that is greater than zero but less that .089 would work?

Comment: @user57172 Now you've got it.